# Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow after copying image

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have a problem where I am trying to show two images on separate threads where both images originate from the same frame, but one of them is a copy of the original frame and the other is the original. The program will be able to display the original frame perfectly, but when the thread with the cloned/copied image reaches imshow() it crashes displaying the error: "Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow".

Is there anyone that can help? 
Regards.

This is the class taking camera input:

```
CameraInput::CameraInput()
{
// Initialize capturing live feed from the camera
capture.open(0);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

 // Couldn't get a device? Throw an error and quit
if(!capture.isOpened())
 {
    qDebug() << "Capture could not be opened successfully.";
 }
 qDebug() << "Capure =" << QThread::currentThreadId();
}

void CameraInput::captureImage()
{
capture >> frame;

if(!frame.empty())
{
    emit capturedImage(&frame);
}
//qDebug() << "capture" << QThread::currentThreadId();
}
```

This is the function run when reaching "*emit capturedImage(&Frame);*". This works fine.

```
void Controll::inputImage(cv::Mat* imgIn)
{
cv::imshow("video", *imgIn);
if (processReady) 
{
    processReady = false;
    emit image(imgIn);
}

emit requestImage();

// see how much time has elapsed
time(&end);

// calculate current FPS
++counterOrg;
sec = difftime (end, start);

fpsOrg = counterOrg / sec;

// will print out Inf until sec is greater than 0
printf("FPS Org stream = %.2f\n", fpsOrg);

}
```

This is the function called when reaching "*emit image(imgIn);*".

```
void Process::processImage(cv::Mat* img)
{
cv::Mat imgHSV = img->clone();
emit (processedImage(&imgHSV));
emit (readyForWork());
}
```

In the following code, we reach an error, the debug line prints, but on imshow() we get the mentioned error. We have also tried using copy constructor and copyTo(), all yield the same results.

```
void Controll::processedImage(cv::Mat* imgIn)
{
qDebug() << "About to show thresh image...";
cv::imshow("thresh", *imgIn);
// see how much time has elapsed
time(&end);

// calculate current FPS
++counterProcessed;
sec = difftime (end, start);

fpsProcessed = counterProcessed / sec;

// will print out Inf until sec is greater than 0
printf("FPS processed stream = %.2f\n", fpsProcessed);
}
```

This is the main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
int c;

// Objects
CameraInput *camera = new CameraInput();
Controll *troller = new Controll();
Process *processer = new Process();
Tracking *tracker = new Tracking();
Serial_Communication *serial = new Serial_Communication("/dev/ttyUSB0");

// Threads
QThread *t1 = new QThread;
QThread *t2 = new QThread;
QThread *t3 = new QThread;
camera->moveToThread(t1);
processer->moveToThread(t2);
tracker->moveToThread(t3);
serial->moveToThread(t3);

// Connections
QObject::connect(t1, SIGNAL(started()), camera, SLOT(captureImage()));
QObject::connect(camera, SIGNAL(capturedImage(cv::Mat*)), troller, SLOT(inputImage(cv::Mat*)));
QObject::connect(t2, SIGNAL(started()), troller, SLOT(processerReady()));
QObject::connect(troller, SIGNAL(image(cv::Mat*)), processer, SLOT(processImage(cv::Mat*)));
QObject::connect(troller, SIGNAL(requestImage()), camera, SLOT(captureImage()));
QObject::connect(processer, SIGNAL(posXposY(int,int)), tracker, SLOT(position(int,int)));
QObject::connect(tracker, SIGNAL(directionAndSpeed(int,int)), serial, SLOT(sendData(int,int)));
QObject::connect(processer, SIGNAL(readyForWork()), troller, SLOT(processerReady()));
QObject::connect(processer, SIGNAL(processedImage(cv::Mat*)), troller, SLOT(processedImage(cv::Mat*)));
// Need to add finish/clean up stuff for terminating threads.

// Starting Threads
t1->start();
t2->start();
t3->start();

// wait for key to exit
while (true) {
     c = cvWaitKey(1);
    if(c!=-1)
    {
        // Add thread termination before breaking the loop.
        // If pressed, break out of the loop
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: please try to avoid passing *pointers* to cv::Mat, use references instead (high danger of thrashing the internal refcounts). also, what you get from the VideoCapture, points to *driver* memory. you'll have to clone the frame, if you want to pass that to another thread (or even use frame outside the capture loop)

Comment: Solved the issue by moving away from pointers and references alltogether. We tried using references as suggested, but then we ended up getting the error: "*QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'cv::Mat&'
(Make sure 'cv::Mat&' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)*". We could not register cv::Mat&, but cv::Mat worked fine.

Comment: @user3434960 you should add and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by moving away from pointers and references alltogether. We tried using references as suggested, but then we ended up getting the error: "QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'cv::Mat&' (Make sure 'cv::Mat&' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)". We could not register cv::Mat&, but cv::Mat worked fine.